# Select all movies that was not watched by the user and limit the result to 20

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all movies that a user has not watched yet.

My SQL query to grab the last 20 movies looks like this:

```
SELECT movies.* FROM movies, hdd WHERE hdd.id=movies.hdd_id and hdd.status='1' and movies.skip!='1' order by id desc limit 20
```

The movie table looks like this:

```
id  int(11) Incrément automatique    
hdd_id  int(20)  
tmdb_id int(20) NULL     
imdb_id text NULL    
file_path   text     
ftp_path    text NULL    
file_name   text     
resolution  text NULL    
timestamp   int(11) NULL     
skip    int(2)   
credits int(2)   
title   varchar(255) NULL    
original_title  varchar(255) NULL    
adult   int(2) NULL  
categ   text NULL    
collection  text NULL    
companies   text NULL    
language    text NULL    
lang    text NULL    
rating  text NULL    
mpaa    text NULL    
tagline text NULL    
overview    text NULL    
budget  text NULL    
homepage    text NULL    
popularity  text NULL    
runtime varchar(255) NULL    
revenue varchar(255) NULL    
release_date    date NULL    
vote_average    varchar(255) NULL    
vote_count  varchar(255) NULL    
movie_poster_path   varchar(255) NULL    
movie_poster    varchar(255) NULL    
movie_backdrop_path varchar(255) NULL    
movie_backdrop  varchar(255) NULL
```

This selects the movies only if the HDD status is online and the crawler did not skip it.

Now the problem is that the watch log is in a separate table:
The table looks like this:

```
id  int(11) Incrément automatique    
type    varchar(255)     
ref int(9) NULL  
membre  int(9) NULL  
counter int(9) NULL  
duration    varchar(255)     
currentTime varchar(255)
```

Membre is the user id and ref is the movie tmdb_id

This is what I tried so fare

```
SELECT movies.* FROM movies, hdd, watch WHERE hdd.id=movies.hdd_id and hdd.status='1' and movies.skip!='1' and (watch.membre='$_SESSION[id]' and watch.ref=movies.tmdb_id) order by id desc limit 20
```

But of course this is not working. I think the output is backwards. Instead of returning the unwatched stuff, it's returning the watched movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to `LEFT JOIN` watch and then check that there is no matching entry in `watch`. I think this will work:

```
SELECT movies.* 
FROM movies
JOIN hdd ON hdd.id = movies.hdd_id AND movies.skip != 1
LEFT JOIN watch ON watch.ref = movies.tmdb_id AND watch.membre='$_SESSION[id]'
WHERE watch.id IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to fliter movies from the whole list which is already watched. using `left join` it can be filtered. try this.

```
SELECT movies.* FROM movies left join watch on watch.ref=movies.tmdb_id, hdd 
WHERE hdd.id=movies.hdd_id and hdd.status='1'and movies.skip!='1' and
watch.membre = '$_SESSION[id]'
order by id desc limit 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to keep it in the same style without JOINs (if that is your preference for whatever reason), you can also do this:

```
SELECT movies.*
FROM movies, hdd
WHERE hdd.id = movies.hdd_id and hdd.status = '1' and movies.skip != '1' and
      NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM watch WHERE watch.membre = '$_SESSION[id]' and watch.ref = movies.tmdb_id)
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 20
```